# Add php in return

Tags: php

I have a code like this that gives undefined errors for "style"

```
$style = !$title && !$icon ? " style='display: none'" : "";
return "<div class='wv_level_box' $style>" . '<div class="wv-badge">' . $afterLabelHtml . '</div><div class="wv-title">' . $title . '</div>' . '</div>';
```

I have fixed the problem by changing the first line to:

```
if (isset($style)) {$style = !$title && !$icon ? " style='display: none'" : "";}
```

However, I don't know how to do the same to the second line where there is a $style variable in the `<div class='wv_level_box' $style>`

Comment: You might need to put parentheses around the condition. Iirc, PHP did something weird with their ternary. It might be a precedence issue. And always include the exact error so we don't need to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` should go **inside** of your conditional:

```
if (isset($style)) {
    $style = !$title && !$icon ? " style='display: none'" : "";
    return "<div class='wv_level_box' $style>" . '<div class="wv-badge">' . $afterLabelHtml . '</div><div class="wv-title">' . $title . '</div>' . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: That's not what I need, return should still work even if the $style is not set.

Comment: @mehmeh that doesn't make much sense. You haven't given us output for either case.

Answer (score 0):

it's normal for your code to have undefined variables so you just need to tell PHP not to show undefined errors.

Here is your new code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$style = !$title && !$icon ? " style='display: none'" : "r";
return "<div class='wv_level_box' $style>" . '<div class="wv-badge">' . $afterLabelHtml . '</div><div class="wv-title">' . $title . '</div>' . '</div>';
```

Comment: [citation needed]. This seems like a bad idea. Hiding errors is almost never the right option.